# Guessing functional form from an equality

Tags: functions, relations, self-learning

Suppose that it is known that two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer, satisfy

$$ f(n) = g(n)-2\,g(n+1)+g(n+2)   $$

From this information, can anything be said about the functional form of $f$ (or $g$)?

Comment: Can't come up with much I'm afraid. Summing over a range of integer gives $\sum_{k=a}^n f(k)=g(n)-2g(n-1)-g(a+1)+g(a+2)$. How does the question arise?

Comment: @blundered_bishop Thank you. Just out of curiosity. In the development of a method two related functions arise by means of that equality. I wish to known if that equality implies something interesting about the functions. For example, it is valid if they are linear functions, and also if they are exponentials. But, not every functional form can satisfy that eq. What have those in common?

Comment: The only really clear thing here is that if, for any function $h$ you define a function $\Delta h$ by $\Delta h(n) = h(n+1) - h(n)$, then we have $f = \Delta \Delta g$. From this, it's clear that nothing can be said about $g$, and since every function $h$ on the nonnegative integers is of the form $\Delta h$ for some $h$, you can't say anything about $f$ either.

Comment: @Anonymous, Thank you. I did not get the meaning of "every function $h$ on the nonnegative integers is of the form $\Delta h$ for some $h$. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Okay, say $g(n) = e^{-n^2}$ and you want to find an function $h(n)$ such that $g = \Delta h$. Then the function $h$ defined by $h(0) = 0$ and $h(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} g(n)$ for $n > 0$ saitisfies $\Delta h = g$. So the function $g$ is $\Delta$ of something. But the same argument could have been used for any other $g$. Therefore, also, any function is $\Delta$ of $\Delta$ of something.

Comment: @Anonymous, Thank you!